# headphones not showing in playback

Tags: laptop, audio, drivers, windows-8.1, microphone

I have windows 8.1 (x64) on an Asus n550jk when I plug in my headphones it doesn't appear in the playback and when I try to use a mic the laptop uses it built-in mic I tried re-installing the driver several times and it didn't work + the Realtek is showing 2 jacks while I have only one is it a driver issue or what?

I already tried checking the disabled devices but no luck and where can I get the right drivers for it?

Comment: Have you checked whether if the headphones and socket are compatible? See [TS/TRS/TRRS/TRRRS: Combating the misconnection epidemic by Allan Tépper - ProVideo Coalition](https://www.provideocoalition.com/ts-trs-trrs-trrrs-combating-the-misconnection-epidemic/) for different standards ...

Comment: yes, they are .